# Thread states in c#

Tags: c#

when i create a thread to do some functions the state of it will first be "running" but after that it will change into "waitsleepjoin"or"stopped" state so :

1. How a thread can reach a waitsleepjoin state?
2. How can a thread can reach the stopped state?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. By calling `Sleep()` or `Join()`, or when waiting for a lock.
2. After it finishes all of its code (after the original method returns)

Comment: what is the difference between them then?

Comment: @Mhd: `WaitSleepJoin` means that it's waiting for something.

Comment: msdn defines the join() as it blocks the calling thread until another thread terminates or the specified time elapsed , by another thread terminates they mean termination of any thread ? can i specify that thread ?

Comment: @Mhd: `Join()` is an instance method.